# Magento 2 swagger-ui error

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, error-log, swagger, swaggerui

I trying this url `http://192.168.1.67/isac/swagger` but I got this error below

```
 500 : {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. 
    Report ID: webapi-5bfe5e3ac4100"} http://192.168.1.67/isac/rest/default/schema?services=all
```

When I checked exception log file I got this below information.

```
[2018-11-28 09:24:07] main.CRITICAL: LogicException: Class "array" does not exist. Please note that namespace must be specified. in /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php:156
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config/ClassReflector.php(103): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->register('array')
#1 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config/ClassReflector.php(72): Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector->extractMethodData(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\MethodReflection))
#2 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/ServiceMetadata.php(119): Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector->reflectClassMethods('Altius\\Customap...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/ServiceMetadata.php(148): Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata->initServicesMetadata()
#4 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Rest/Swagger/Generator.php(913): Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata->getServicesConfig()
#5 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(278): Magento\Webapi\Model\Rest\Swagger\Generator->getListOfServices()
#6 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(214): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processSchemaRequest()
#7 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /var/www/html/isac/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#11 /var/www/html/isac/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#12 {main}

Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-5bfe5eb799b72; Message: Class "array" does not exist. Please note that namespace must be specified. in /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(LogicException))
#1 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(LogicException))
#2 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /var/www/html/isac/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/html/isac/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#6 /var/www/html/isac/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#7 {main} [] []
```

It's very confusing and like toughest puzzle game. How to resolve this and get api from swagger?

Answer (score 3):

This error due to undefined return type. you cannot defined array as return type. If I am not wrong then you want to return it as associative array so check below code.

You need to define it like below

```
/**
 * Get Slides
 *
 * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\KeyValueInterface[]  
 */
public function getSlides();
```

Please Check, in your case there will be array as return type in place of \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\KeyValueInterface.

**KeyValueInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api\Data;

/**
 * KeyValueInterface.
 * @api
 */
interface KeyValueInterface
{
    const LABEL_KEY = "key";
    const LABEL_VALUE = "value";

    /**
     * Get key
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey();

    /**
     * Set key
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function setKey($key);

    /**
     * Get value
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue();

    /**
     * Set value
     * 
     * @param string $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setValue($value);
}
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Was it helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have a custom api module `Altius_Customap` which is creating the issue and you have to remove or disable it and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in your debugger at the `try/catch` that throws a `\LogicException` in `\Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::register`.
There you can see the offending class name and method. In my case it was coming from the module `Afterpay_Payment`.